# Why GWC and WMS tile looks different?

Tags: geoserver

I have `Geoserver 2.9.4` and have a layer published in.
Now I do two pretty same requests:

To GWC

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=map_0041000003EA&SRS=EPSG%3A100000&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A100000&STYLES=&BBOX=1615955.2149769105%2C341138.45723674074%2C1616031.6520051956%2C341214.8942650259
```

[image]

To WMS

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=map_0041000003EA&SRS=EPSG%3A100000&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A100000&STYLES=&BBOX=1615955.2149769105%2C341138.45723674074%2C1616031.6520051956%2C341214.8942650259
```

[image]

As you can see, the symbol on a GWC tile looks bigger. So I want to find explanation. Why does it look bigger?

**UPDATE**

After i updated Geoserver to 2.12.4, my GWC layers starts throw errors about resolution do not match. So i create new gridset based on resolution from error. And now i can get my gwc layer only on scales what declared in gridset.
This is new feature?

But my first probles solved. Now WMS and GWC layer on same scale looks the same.

Comment: GWC is constructing the output from cachad tiles. What you see would happen if GWC takes tiles with a bit better resolution and stretches them to suit with the scale that you used in the GetMap request. Do you know it your BBOX fits exactly with the tile limits?

Comment: @user30184 I take a GWC request URL and change `gwc/service/wms` to `wms` in it. And expected to see simular image. My experiment does not correct?

Comment: It feels like a reasonable test because you do not seem to use metatiles or gutter when seeding. Metatiles should not even matter. Try to catch the same issue with some of the demo layers like "tiger-ny". Current GeoServer version is 2.12.4 and I recommend to update first.

Comment: @user30184 I updated Geoserver and add details in question.

Comment: The full-WMS mode is off by default, read the manual for activating it http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html. Perhaps this blog gives also useful hints for fine-tuning your GWC-WMS. But if you ask map at scales which are between the cached resolutions the stretching of symbology and texts is unavoidable.

Comment: @user30184 Adding `<fullWMS>true</fullWMS>` tag into `geowebcache.xml` solve my problem. I thought that wms interration checkbox in Geoserver webinterface do same but i wa wrong.